# How do I create a callback that sends data from one unit to another?

Tags: delphi

I have `Unit1.pas` which is my main unit file, and I have another unit file `TimerUpdates.pas` that programmatically receives events, such as `Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);`

I want to know, how can I implement callbacks, and when should I use them over other methods?

Now I know I could respond to `Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);` with `Unit1.Callback(Timer : TTimer);` and that would call it, but I'd prefer to know why I should or shouldn't use that over the other callback method.

Still learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

Unit1.pas

```pascal
uses
  ..., TimerUpdates;

procedure TMainForm.Callback(Timer : TTimer);
begin
  ...
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TimerUpdates.OnTimerCallback := Callback;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TimerUpdates.OnTimerCallback := nil;
end;
```

TimerUpdates.pas

```
interface

uses
 ..., ExtCtrls;

type
  TCallback = procedure(Timer: TTimer) of object;

var
  OnTimerCallback: TCallback;

implementation

...

procedure TSomeClass.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(OnTimerCallback) then
    OnTimerCallback(TTimer(Sender));
end;

end.
```

Comment: Beginners might enjoy comments in the code, i.e. which methods are created thru the IDE and which need to be added to the Form's definition. Or why setting to `nil` is done.

Comment: @Ben that information should have been added as an edit to your question, not put in comments. In any case, `ForLoopUnit.OnLoopCallback := Callback(i);` needs to be `ForLoopUnit.OnLoopCallback := Callback;` instead, and `type TCallback = procedure(i: integer);` needs to be `type TCallback = procedure(i: integer) of object;` instead. Then it should work.

Answer (score -1):

for assign your event procedure, You must use some class procedure to avoid 'method pointer and regular procedure' problem.

you don't need to create a new class, you can use TForm instead of myClass

Unit1.pas :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

  procedure CreateTimer;

implementation

uses Vcl.ExtCtrls, TimerUpdates;

type
  TmyClass = class
    procedure onTimer(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var myClass : TmyClass;


procedure CreateTimer;
begin
  Timer := TTimer.Create(nil);
  Timer.Interval := 1000;
  Timer.OnTimer := myClass.onTimer;
  Timer.Enabled := True;
end;

{ TmyClass }

procedure TmyClass.onTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //do what you want
end;

end.
```

TimerUpdates.pas

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses Vcl.ExtCtrls;

var
  Timer: TTimer;

implementation

end.
```